# JavaScript convert an array of bytes to JSON and back

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am having trouble converting a JSON string back to byte array. My byte array was converted to JSON string through JSON.stringify(bytes). If I use JSON.parse to convert the string back to JS, I only get an object, not an array any more.
For example in the JS console:

```
> var bytes = new Int32Array([101, 102, 103]);
> var s = JSON.stringify(bytes);
> s;
"{"0":101,"1":102,"2":103}"
> var a = JSON.parse(s);

> a;
Object {0: 101, 1: 102, 2: 103}
```

How can I get the original byte array back?

Comment: You have to create a new one with the data in `a`. JSON doesn't have a representation of "typed arrays", just arrays.

Comment: why can't you use the array itself without converting to Int32Array

Comment: b/c I want to send the JSON string across the net.

Comment: you can send the array as well `JSON.stringify([101, 102, 103]);` which will give you "[101, 102, 103]" ... does the data need to be sent in this specific format?

Comment: I was hoping to have an elegant solution w/o a nasty iteration.

Comment: @gp, my array is already built as an audio buffer, thus I can't build the JSON string that way.

Comment: then you will have to iterate and convert the object to array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var arr = []; 
for(var p in Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a)) {
    arr[p] = a[p];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @gp, that worked. Though I was originally looking for a simple function call w/o iteration, your answer is simple enough and acceptable.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to represent a typed array as an array in JSON and not as an object, you can [pass a replacer function as second argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Parameters) to `JSON.stringify` and [convert the typed array to a normal array first](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays#Conversion_to_normal_arrays):

```
var bytes = new Int32Array([101, 102, 103]);
var s = JSON.stringify(bytes, function(k, v) {
    if (v instanceof  Int32Array) {
        return Array.apply([], v);
    }
    return v;
});
// s is now "[101, 102, 103]"
```

Comment: This is almost but not quite working as expected for me. When I stringify an object containing a typed array property value, the resulting JSON has the array literal quoted as in '{"a": 1, "b": "[101, 102, 103]"}'

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to convert a TypedArray into an Array just before the stringification process.

```
JSON.stringify(Array.from(new Int32Array([101, 102, 103])))
```

Comment: Please explain your answer. Code only answers are not that useful to future visitors